# How to Check Dynamically Background Color Changes

Tags: jquery

I have a input textfield. When I strat to type a hex value without #, its background color changes to new color, I was typing. And the text color should be white or black depend new background color brightness. I can do that when I hit the enter after finished to type. How can I do that dynamically, I mean whitout hitting enter? My codes:

```
$(document).on("focus", "input[name='colorCode']", function (){
  $(this).keyup(function (options) {
    var myBgColor = "#" + $(this).val();
    $(this).css("background-color", myBgColor);
    var bgColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    var settings = $.extend({
                      darkText: "#000",
                      lightText: "#fff"
                     }, options);
    var rgb = bgColor.substring(bgColor.indexOf('(') + 1, bgColor.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
        red = rgb[0],
        green = rgb[1],
        blue = rgb[2],
        brightness = Math.sqrt((.241 * (red * red)) + (.671 * (green * green)) + (.068 * (blue * blue)));
    if (brightness > 128) {
        $(this).css('color', settings.darkText);
    } else {
            $(this).css('color', settings.lightText);
        }
  });
})
```

Any suggestion please...

**EDIT:** I don't have to hit enter, after typing of first 3 character, pressing any key changes the text color.

Comment: What part of your code not change dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you taught to change color of input box automatically without pressing enter, your code is good.

Load this into index.html and start into browser:

This is `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Color change</title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body class="background-color">
  <input name="colorCode"/>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

This is `load.js` file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("focus", "input[name='colorCode']", function (){
  $(this).keyup(function (options) {
    var myBgColor = "#" + $(this).val();
    $(this).css("background-color", myBgColor);
    var bgColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    var settings = $.extend({
                      darkText: "#000",
                      lightText: "#fff"
                     }, options);
    var rgb = bgColor.substring(bgColor.indexOf('(') + 1, bgColor.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
        red = rgb[0],
        green = rgb[1],
        blue = rgb[2],
        brightness = Math.sqrt((.241 * (red * red)) + (.671 * (green * green)) + (.068 * (blue * blue)));
    if (brightness > 128) {
        $(this).css('color', settings.darkText);
    } else {
            $(this).css('color', settings.lightText);
        }
  });
})
});
```

Put this on localhost in same dir.

[Check on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kxf4emL/)

Comment: Thank Vladimir, I didn't try it. But is there a way to do that, if I want to put this code in script file and link it just before colesing of body tag? Because I have some similar issues and if I can find solution this way, it will be better.